# If the Lorenz curve for a country is $f(x)=x^k$, how to calculate the value of $k$ since the Gini index is 0.9?

Tags: calculus

If the Lorenz curve for a certain country is $f(x)=x^k$, how do I determine the value of $k$ if the Gini index is 0.9?

I set the formula equal to 0.9, then I took the anti-derivative of the formula but it seemed wrong to me.

Comment: What are the domains of $x$ and $k$ ?

Comment: The problem doesn't say anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The support of a Lorenz curve is $(0,1).$

We know that the Gini index calculation is as follows:

$$\frac{9}{10}=2\bigg(\frac{1}{2}-\int_0^1 x^kdx \bigg) $$ and we need to find the $k$ that makes this true.

$$ \frac{9}{10}=1-\frac{2}{k+1}. $$

The answer is $k=19.$

(Also see the graphic on this page under the "Definition" heading: [Gini Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient))